# Codeigniter redirect changing on login page

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am trying to redirect users to the page they were viewing before attempting to login. For example, if they were looking at baseurl/people/abraham_lincoln and then decided to log in, after they login they would be redirected to baseurl/people/abraham_lincoln. The weird thing is that it is working for some URLs and not others. For some URLs, I am getting "javascript/jsFunctions.js" appended as the URL instead of the URL they were previously on.

At the top of every controller, I set a session variable to do my redirect:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('Redirect', current_url());
```

I am printing this session variable to the top of my controller and at the top of my log in view for testing purposes. Here are a few results I am receiving when I go to my login.

**An example of a URL that's working:**

URL I attempt to log in from:

```
baseURL/people
```

What gets printed at the top of my controller as my Redirect session variable:

```
baseURL/people
```

What gets printed at the top of my log in view as my Redirect session variable:

```
baseURL/people
```

**An example of a URL that's not working:**

URL I attempt to log in from:

```
baseURL/people/abraham_lincoln
```

What gets printed at the top of my controller as my Redirect session variable:

```
baseURL/people/abraham_lincoln
```

What gets printed at the top of my log in view as my Redirect session variable:

```
baseURL/people/javascript/jsFunctions.js
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but I am also routing some of these URLs from the routes.php file:

```
$route['people/(:any)'] = "people/index/$1";
$route['people/(:any)/(:num)'] = "people/index/$1/$2";
```

I have tried to build my session variable many different ways, including:

```
current_url()
base_url().uri_string()
base_url().$this->uri->segment(1)....
base_url().$this->uri->rsegment(1)....
```

If anyone can think of why I'm getting those javascript variables instead of the URL I'm looking for I would appreciate any input.

Thanks!

P.S. I forgot to mention that if I refresh a page that isn't working, for example the abraham_lincoln page, and then go to login, I receive the correct Redirect session variable. Almost like it isn't getting set correctly the first time through, but don't know how I can solve this since I have tried setting the session variable both at the very top and right before the views are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

the use case should only apply to the login process.  thus putting this on the top of every controller would probably not what we want.

instead of putting current_url in session at the start, you should append it to the login link

```
<?php echo anchor('/home/login/' . url_encode(current_url()), 'login');?>
```

in the login function

```
<?php
    public function login($redirecturl) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        // etc.
        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $query = "select id from users where username=? and password=sha(?)";
            // etc.
            $this->session->set_userdata('userid', $row->id);
            redirect($redirecturl);
        } else {
            $data['redirecturl']=$redirecturl;
            $data['content']='loginview';
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }
    }
?>
```

In the login view

```
<?php
    echo form_open('/home/login/' . url_encode($redirecturl));
    // etc.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still getting the javascript.js files appended to the current_url() even when I attach it to a url in my view. Not sure why. I currently have a solution in place using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] which seems to be working at the moment. I know it's not 100% reliable, but is working for now. Thanks again for your response.